# Create /Output a New Text file txt from a dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary, text, output

if I have a sample dictionary is it possible to output it to a new or existing .txt file?

```
d = {'Jim':'233-5467', 'Bob':'643-7894', 'Anne':'478-4392', 'Jill':'952-4532'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No modules needed.

```
myfile = open('test.txt','w')
d = {'Jim':'233-5467', 'Bob':'643-7894', 'Anne':'478-4392', 'Jill':'952-4532'}
myfile.writelines('{}:{} '.format(k,v) for k, v in d.items())
myfile.close()
```

Content of 'test.txt' :

> Jill:952-4532 Bob:643-7894 Jim:233-5467 Anne:478-4392

Answer (score 1):

Use `json` module:

```
import json
json.dump(d, open("file.json", "w"))
```

---

Or as @ZdaR suggested:

```
with open("file.json", "w") as out_file:
    json.dump(d, out_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert it to json, `json` can represent `dict` in txt format.

```
import json
json.dump({'Jim':'233-5467', 'Bob':'643-7894', 'Anne':'478-4392', 'Jill':'952-4532'}, open('yourfile.json', 'w'))
```